# multiple gremlin commands combined as one

Tags: node.js, neo4j, gremlin, node-neo4j

im using `nodejs`, `neo4j` with `node-neo4j` and trying to put multiple `gremlin` command together
and im stuck with this problem
if i execute the commands one after another like

```
x = [] as Set
y  = [] as Set
g.v(id1).both('friend').aggregate(x)
g.v(id2).both('friend').aggregate(y)
x.retainAll(y);
x
```

it works fine and a list of nodes is returned
on the other hand if i write it like

```
x = [] as Set;y  = [] as Set;g.v(id1).both('friend').aggregate(x);g.v(id2).both(
'friend').aggregate(y);x.retainAll(y);x
```

nothing is returned
read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433802/how-to-chain-commands-in-gremlin) which says that

> if your last command is not an iterator then you will have to manually
>   iterate of the sequence

but dont know how to apply this in my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

oops!
i was missing a very simple thing `.iterate()`
this command now works

```
x = [] as Set;y  = [] as Set;g.v(id1).both('friend').aggregate(x).iterate();g.v(id2).both('friend').aggregate(y).iterate();x.retainAll(y);x
```